# How to get 1080p video from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video

When I import a 1080p video using `UIImagePickerController`, then ask it what the size is, it reports it to be only 720p.

Here's how I open the Image Picker:

```
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    picker.videoQuality = .TypeHigh
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.findButton.frame
    picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then, when the user chooses an image:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let readMovieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]
    // ...
}
```

Later I ask for the size: (this bit is in Objective-c)

```
NSDictionary *options = @{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey:@YES};
AVURLAsset *readMovieAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:readMovieURL options:options];

AVAssetTrack * track = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];

// Why is it 720p?
CGSize size = track.naturalSize;
```

How can I let a user select a 1080p video from their library and later work with it at full resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`. That specifically refers to the processed (compressed) video. Switching to the following gives me the full 1080p video:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    // Reference URL instead
    let readMovieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]
}
```

I have no idea how to prevent the picker from going through the compression process in the first place.

Comment: I just realized that this method ignores any edits the user made. Not good :(